# <h1>-tag with an background-image underline with fixed width

Tags: width, fixed, underline

I'm new to stackoverflow.com and this is my first post so:

I want to have a h1-text with underline. This underline will be an image and it should have a fixed width of 420px. The text in h1 will often be wider than the 420px, but sometimes shorter. Now I know that these are the solutions to get the underline as an image, but how do I set the fixed width for the underline only?

```
h1 {
background-image:url('images/hrBg.jpg');
background-position: 0px bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the background image with the width of 420px.

Then use the following css

```css
    h1 {
      background:url('https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5834a5fd9de4bb511a531745/1572560269010-YEGGAHEJ1O3AG5OAMO7M/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kEnLsHrnzeww6Ind1smsg7N7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QPOohDIaIeljMHgDF5CVlOqpeNLcJ80NK65_fV7S1UZMvWVOiG2zXPfa_FplZumXplNQ97KbZI2EjeHIoBACLnr1xKjsq_-rO8kOgOtwYvw/Burning-Up-BG.jpg?format=2500w') no-repeat left bottom;
      min-width:420px;
    }
```

```html
<h1>Text here</h1>
```

This will ensure that the background is shown only once to with of 420px.  I have added the `min-width` property in case the content of `h1` is smaller than 420px.  The `no-repeat` property ensures that the background is shown only once as we have set the length via the actual image.